# python - Given a format and a string, get info from that string

Tags: python, regex, format

I want to do something similar to the strptime method in the datetime module. Given a format and a string, change the format of that string and return the new string. So for example I have the file name of an episode of a tv series, I call the function to change the format of the file name specifying where the title is, where the episode is, the quality, etc.

```
def change_format(file_name, format, season=1):
    title = # Get the title applying the format to the string
    episode = # Get the episode applying the format to the string
    season = # Get the season applying the format to the string or from the variable in the function
    quality # Get the quality applying the format to the string
    return f'{title} + S{season}E{episode} [{quality}]'
```

Some of the info may or may not be given (For example, if the quality is not given then don't use it in the return) and there can be extra info.

```
change_format('Some Title Here - 1 [1080p] [CDI3989AFM]', '%t - %e [%q][%i]')
```

Here, %t is the title, %e is the episode, %q is the quality and %i is some extra info.
The title is in 3 words, so maybe you should specify the number of words?

Expected Output:

```
"Some Title Here S01E01 [1080p] [CDI3989AFM]"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex for this as this:

```py
import re

r = re.match('(.*).*(\[.*\]).*(\[.*\])', 'Some Title Here - 1 [1080p] [CDI3989AFM]')
r.group(1) # Some Title Here - 1 
r.group(2) # [1080p] 
r.group(2) # [CDI3989AFM]
```

Comment: But there will be files with a different format, so i would have to make a different regex to each format?

Comment: @User yes, you can not just says `%t` is always title